# get ubuntu terminal to send an escape sequence (control+shift+up)

Tags: terminal, emacs, gnome-terminal, escape-characters

This problem starts when I use emacs ( with -nw option).
Let me first explain it.
I tried to define hotkey (for emacs) as following

```
(global-set-key [(control shift up)] 'other-window)
```

but it doesn't work (no error, just doesn't work), neither does

```
(global-set-key [(control shift down)] 'other-window)
```

But

```
(global-set-key [(control shift right)] 'other-window)
```

and

```
(global-set-key [(control shift left)] 'other-window)
```

work!

But because the last two key combinations are used by emacs (as default), I don't wanna change them for other functions.

So how could I make <kbd>control-shift-up</kbd> and <kbd>control-shift-down</kbd> work?

I have googled "(control shift up)", it seems that <kbd>control-shift-up</kbd> is used by other people, (but not very few results).

In the Stack Overflow forum, Gille answered me as following:

<kbd>Ctrl+Shift+Up</kbd> does send a signal to your computer, but your terminal emulator is apparently not transmitting any escape sequence for it. So your problem is in two parts. First you must get your terminal emulator to send an escape sequence, which depends on your terminal emulator, and is Super User material, or Unix.SE if you're using a unix system. Then you need to declare the escape sequence in Emacs, and my answer explains that part

So I come here for this question:

How do I get my terminal (I use ubuntu 10.04, and the built-in terminal) to send an escape sequence for <kbd>Control+Shift+Up</kbd> <kbd>Control+Shift+down</kbd>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ubuntu uses GNOME and `gnome-terminal`. According to its documentation ([in version 2.30](http://mail.gnome.org/archives/commits-list/2010-January/msg01623.html)), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Down</kbd> are used for navigating the scrollback buffer, and there doesn't seem to be any way to turn this "feature" off (aside from modifying the source code of `vte`, the terminal library).

---

To patch vte on Ubuntu 10.04:

1. Rebuild `vte`, the terminal emulation library:

   1. Install software required for compiling:

      ```
      sudo apt-get install git-core fakeroot
      sudo apt-get build-dep vte
      ```
   2. Download `vte` source code and apply the patch:

      ```
      cd /tmp
      git clone git://gist.github.com/771667.git patches
      apt-get source vte
      cd vte-0.23.5
      patch -p1 < ../patches/vte-0.23.5.patch
      ```
   3. Make a Debian package and install it:

      ```
      dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc
      sudo dpkg -i ../libvte9_0.23.5-*.deb
      ```
2. Close all `gnome-terminal` processes.
3. Enjoy -- until the next `vte` update...

---

Patch for 0.23:

```
diff -ur vte-0.23.5/src/vte.c vte-0.23.5+patched/src/vte.c
--- vte-0.23.5/src/vte.c    2010-01-14 02:46:18.000000000 +0200
+++ vte-0.23.5+patched/src/vte.c    2011-01-09 15:19:01.000000000 +0200
@@ -4948,26 +4948,6 @@
            }
            break;
        /* Keypad/motion keys. */
-       case GDK_KP_Up:
-       case GDK_Up:
-           if (modifiers & GDK_CONTROL_MASK 
-                            && modifiers & GDK_SHIFT_MASK) {
-               vte_terminal_scroll_lines(terminal, -1);
-               scrolled = TRUE;
-               handled = TRUE;
-               suppress_meta_esc = TRUE;
-           }
-           break;
-       case GDK_KP_Down:
-       case GDK_Down:
-           if (modifiers & GDK_CONTROL_MASK
-                            && modifiers & GDK_SHIFT_MASK) {
-               vte_terminal_scroll_lines(terminal, 1);
-               scrolled = TRUE;
-               handled = TRUE;
-               suppress_meta_esc = TRUE;
-           }
-           break;
        case GDK_KP_Page_Up:
        case GDK_Page_Up:
            if (modifiers & GDK_SHIFT_MASK) {
```

---

Patch for 0.26:

```
diff -ur vte-0.26.2/src/vte.c vte-0.26.2+patched/src/vte.c
--- vte-0.26.2/src/vte.c    2010-11-13 14:18:41.000000000 +0200
+++ vte-0.26.2+patched/src/vte.c    2011-01-09 15:06:54.870000002 +0200
@@ -5153,26 +5153,6 @@
            }
            break;
        /* Keypad/motion keys. */
-       case GDK_KEY (KP_Up):
-       case GDK_KEY (Up):
-           if (modifiers & GDK_CONTROL_MASK 
-                            && modifiers & GDK_SHIFT_MASK) {
-               vte_terminal_scroll_lines(terminal, -1);
-               scrolled = TRUE;
-               handled = TRUE;
-               suppress_meta_esc = TRUE;
-           }
-           break;
-       case GDK_KEY (KP_Down):
-       case GDK_KEY (Down):
-           if (modifiers & GDK_CONTROL_MASK
-                            && modifiers & GDK_SHIFT_MASK) {
-               vte_terminal_scroll_lines(terminal, 1);
-               scrolled = TRUE;
-               handled = TRUE;
-               suppress_meta_esc = TRUE;
-           }
-           break;
        case GDK_KEY (KP_Page_Up):
        case GDK_KEY (Page_Up):
            if (modifiers & GDK_SHIFT_MASK) {
```

Comment: Thank you very much! But could you teach me something? First of all, "patch" adds your code to the source code of vte? (Sorry, but I just start to learn C, and still on the level of "if" "while"..etc) If next time, I want to something similar (for example, say control+shift+backspace), could I just replace "up" in your code with "backspace", then do the commands you mentioned in your comment? Thank you again!

Comment: @user: 1) Sort of. This particular patch only _removes_ the code that would otherwise steal these two keypresses. In the output of `diff -u`, added lines start with a `+` and removed lines start with a `-`. 2) You would have to edit `vte.c` itself, not my or anyone else's patch. But remember that not all keys _have_ their own sequences.

Comment: @user: Also, I forgot to add `sudo apt-get build-dep vte` to instructions in that page; you will probably need to run the command before doing `dpkg-buildpackage`.

Comment: I extract the files from vite_1.0+snv834-5.orig.tar.gz, and there are many folders, and in each folder, there are many .cpp and .hpp files. What's the best way to find out the part needed modify? (In my mind, I think I need to know some basic knoledge to figure out a keyword, then do something like "search a word in all files inside a folder")?

Comment: @grawity: I have already done the steps you mentioned, and it works fine. Thanks

Comment: @user: It's src/vte.c (the package is vte, not vite, and it's in C, not C++) -- but you don't need to know that if you have a prepared patch to apply. // If you're satisfied with this "fix", see ["marking answers as accepted"](http://superuser.com/faq#howtoask). But a much better solution would be to file a bug in GNOME Bugzilla, asking for ability to use Ctrl-Shift-arrows in programs.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> do seem to be captured by the gnome default terminal, however I tend to use a terminal called "Terminator" on 10.04, where these keys do not seem to be mapped.